# Trying to figure out what changes I need to make for this code to work correctly. Using Visual Studio

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void getMaximumPositive(int* arr, int size, int* max)
{
    max = nullptr;      //Set default value of max pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > 0)     //Only positive numbers are considered while locating the maximum
        {

            if (max == nullptr)
                max = &arr[i];
            else if (arr[i] > * max)
                max = &arr[i];
        }
    }
}

void getMaximumNegative(int* arr, int size, int* max)
{
    max = nullptr;      //Set default value of max pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < 0)     //Only negative numbers are considered while locating the maximum
        {

            if (max == nullptr)
                max = &arr[i];
            else if (arr[i] > * max)
                max = &arr[i];
        }
    }
}

void printArrayForwards(int* arr, int size)
{
    cout << "Array contents (Forwards): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " : ";
    cout << endl;
}

void printArrayBackwards(int* arr, int size)
{
    cout << "Array contents (Backwards): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << *(arr - i - 1) << " : ";
    cout << endl;
}

void swapMaxtoFront(int* arr, int* max_address)
{
    if (max_address == nullptr)
        return;                 //Do nothing if max_address is null

    //Print the addresses and their corresponding values of the first element and the maximum element of the array
    cout << endl << "Swapping elements:" << endl;
    cout << "Address 1: " << arr << " Value: " << *arr << endl;
    cout << "Address 2: " << max_address << " Value: " << *max_address << endl << endl;

    //Code for the swap
    int temp = *arr;
    *arr = *max_address;
    *max_address = temp;

    max_address = arr;
}

void PrintArray(int* arr, int size)
{
    printArrayForwards(arr, size);
    printArrayBackwards(arr, size);
}

int main()
{
    //Initialize pointers to null
    int* array = nullptr;       //Do Not Change This Variable Definition 
    int* max = nullptr;         //Do Not Change This Variable Definition

    int arr_size;

    cout << "Enter the size of your array: ";
    cin >> arr_size;
    array = new int[arr_size];          //Reserve memory for array of size given by user
    cout << "Enter array elements: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Element " << i + 1 << " of " << arr_size << " : ";
        cin >> *(array++);
    }

    PrintArray(array, arr_size);

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl << "Finding maximum positive number in array..." << endl;

    getMaximumPositive(array, arr_size, max);   //Max should point to the Maximum positive value in the array

    swapMaxtoFront(array, max);         //Swap the maximum positive number with the first element of the array

    PrintArray(array, arr_size);        //Print array with swapped values.

    //Print maximum positive number
    cout << endl;
    if (max == nullptr)
        cout << "*******No positive numbers found in array" << endl;
    else
        cout << "*******Maximum positive number in array: " << *max << endl;        //Max should point to the Maximum positive value in the array, which should now be the first element
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;


    cout << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl << "Finding maximum negative number in array..." << endl;

    getMaximumNegative(array, arr_size, max);   //Max should point to the Maximum negative value in the array

    swapMaxtoFront(array, max);         //Swap the maximum negative number with the first element of the array

    PrintArray(array, arr_size);        //Print array with swapped values.

    //Print maximum negative number
    cout << endl;
    if (max == nullptr)
        cout << "*******No negative numbers found in array" << endl;
    else
        cout << "*******Maximum negative number in array: " << *max << endl;        //Max should point to the Maximum negative value in the array, which should now be the first element
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;

    delete[] array;
    delete max;
    array = nullptr;
    max = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (That I am trying to look for):

Enter the size of your array: 4

Enter array elements:

Element 1 of 4 : 2

Element 2 of 4 : 8

Element 3 of 4 : 4

Element 4 of 4 : 6

Array contents (Forwards):

2 : 8 : 4 : 6 :

Array contents (Backwards):

6: 4 : 8 : 2

---

Finding maximum positive number in array...

Swapping elements:

Address 1: 015E10A0 Value: 2

Address 2: 015E10A4 Value: 8

Array contents (Forwards)

8 : 2 : 4 : 6 :

Array contents (Backwards)

6 : 4 : 2 : 8 :

*******Maximum positive number in array: 8

---

---

Finding maximum negative number in array...

Array contents (Forwards):

8 : 2 : 4 : 6 :

Array contenes (Backwards):

6: 4 : 2 : 8 :

*******No negative numbers found in array

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Using the name `max` after having done `using namespace std;` is probably a bad idea as it'll easily clash with `std::max()` and `array` may clash with `std::array`.

Comment: It is called using a debugger, with a minimal reproducible complete example.

Comment: @user12335271 I've looked it through and made it give the output you expect but  every time I looked at it, I found a new glitch. I suggest that you break down problems in smaller pieces in the future and try to make one little piece good at a time. Make test code for your functions so that it doesn't become such a big mystery when it fails. Debug printouts can also help a lot to see why and where it starts failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem I noticed was what you do with `array`:

```
    array = new int[arr_size];

    //...

    for(size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        cin >> *(array++);                 // here you step array
    }

    // ... and you use the final pointer "array" everywhere, undefined behaviour. It
    //     points one element outside of the area you allocated

    delete[] array; // the final nail in the coffin,
```

Fix:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        cout << "Element " << i + 1 << " of " << arr_size << " : ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }
```

With that fixed, this becomes a problem:

```
void printArrayBackwards(int* arr, int size) {
    cout << "Array contents (Backwards): " << endl;

    // arr points at the start, so arr - 0 - 1 points before start here:

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << *(arr - i - 1) << " : ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Fix:

```
void printArrayBackwards(int* arr, int size) {
    cout << "Array contents (Backwards): " << endl;
    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) cout << arr[i] << " : ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Another thing is the `getMaximumPositive` and `getMaximumNegative` functions. You don't return a pointer to the max value in `max`. I changed it to a reference to an `int*`:

```
void getMaximumPositive(int* arr, int size, int*& max) {
    max = nullptr; // Set default value of max pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > 0)
        { // Only positive numbers are considered while locating the maximum
            if(max == nullptr)
                max = &arr[i];
            else if(arr[i] > *max)
                max = &arr[i];
        }
    }
}

void getMaximumNegative(int* arr, int size, int*& max) {
    max = nullptr; // Set default value of max pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < 0)
        { // Only negative numbers are considered while locating the maximum
            if(max == nullptr)
                max = &arr[i];
            else if(arr[i] > *max)
                max = &arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I also removed the `delete max` you had. It is a pointer to an `int` inside the `array` that you delete with `delete[] array`. You should not delete that.

Another function where to don't return the value via the parameter is in `swapMaxtoFront`. I changed that to:

```
void swapMaxtoFront(int* arr, int*& max_address) {
//...
```

[Full code](https://godbolt.org/z/HTtSYC) with your input mocked with
`std::istringstream cin{"4 2 8 4 6"};`

Answer (score 0):

You passed pointer as parameter.

To receive a pointer, you should pass pointer of pointer.

You can write as this..

```
void getMaximumPositive(int* arr, int size, int** max) {
...
*max = &arr[ i ];
...
}
...
getMaximumPositive( arr, 10, &max );
```